# javascript in html click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Where is my wrong?
I have a button in html

`<a class="btn btn-warning btn-mini publish-btn" href="#" data-rowid="@computer.id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Outdated</a>`

and my model

```
<fieldset style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" />  : Publish Now<br/>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" />  : Schedule Publish<br/>
</fieldset>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submitBtnPublishId"  >OK</button>              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="submitBtnSpublishId"     >Cancel</button>
```

and my js

```
$(function(){
 $/-("a.publish-btn").click(function(e) {
 var obj = $(this);
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#submitBtnPublishId').click(clickOnPublish);
 function clickOnPublish()
 {}})})
```

is not working when click OK button. Why??

Comment: What exactly is `$/-("a.publish-btn")` supposed to be? Is that intentional, or a typo you introduced while typing out your question?

Comment: it is a main button when you clicked it, there appear a model window   my OK button is in this window and i wanna do action when clicked OK  button

Comment: Not with `$/-` it's not. Those symbols are actually important, they have meaning. What you've typed is gibberish. I assume you meant to type `$('a.publish-btn')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong $ sign correct it as follow

```
$(function(){
 $("publish-btn").click(function(e) {
 var obj = $(this);
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#submitBtnPublishId').click(clickOnPublish);
 function clickOnPublish()
 {}})})
```

Comment: there is no change :(